# redirect user to current page with some querystring using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a person clicks on a link, I want to do this:

1. grab the text from a textbox
2. encode the text
3. redirect to currentpage.aspx?search=textboxvalue

I have this so far but its not working:

```
window.location.href = "?search=" + escape( $("#someId").val());
```

Answer (score 28):

I needed to do something similar to what you wanted so I put together a function that allows you to do it. I hope it is found useful. I have tested it pretty extensively and not found any issues, please don't hesitate to let me know if any issues are found.

### The Function

```
function reloadWithQueryStringVars (queryStringVars) {
    var existingQueryVars = location.search ? location.search.substring(1).split("&") : [],
        currentUrl = location.search ? location.href.replace(location.search,"") : location.href,
        newQueryVars = {},
        newUrl = currentUrl + "?";
    if(existingQueryVars.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < existingQueryVars.length; i++) {
            var pair = existingQueryVars[i].split("=");
            newQueryVars[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }
    }
    if(queryStringVars) {
        for (var queryStringVar in queryStringVars) {
            newQueryVars[queryStringVar] = queryStringVars[queryStringVar];
        }
    }
    if(newQueryVars) { 
        for (var newQueryVar in newQueryVars) {
            newUrl += newQueryVar + "=" + newQueryVars[newQueryVar] + "&";
        }
        newUrl = newUrl.substring(0, newUrl.length-1);
        window.location.href = newUrl;
    } else {
        window.location.href = location.href;
    }
}
```

### How to Use It

The function accepts an object literal as its only argument. The object literal should contain the query string variable(s) that you want to reload the page with. It accounts for existing variables and will override an existing one if you specify it in the object literal you pass.

So, lets say our location is `http://localhost/helloworld.php` and I want to redirect to the current page with a query string variable `foo` whose value should be `bar`, I'd call the function as follows:

```
reloadWithQueryStringVars({"foo": "bar"});
```

The browser will navigate to `http://localhost/helloworld.php?foo=bar`. And If I pass the function the following:

```
reloadWithQueryStringVars({"foo": "bar2"});
```

The browser will navigate to `http://localhost/helloworld.php?foo=bar2`.

As the function accepts a object literal, you can pass multiple properties to the function for multiple query string vars. If I'm still at `http://localhost/helloworld.php?foo=bar2` and I call function as follows

```
reloadWithQueryStringVars({"foo": "bar3", "answer": "42", "bacon": "tasty"});
```

The browser will navigate to `http://localhost/helloworld.php?foo=bar3&answer=42&bacon=tasty`

### Your Use Case

In answer to the question however, you'd call the function as follows:

```
reloadWithQueryStringVars({"search": escape( $("#someId").val() )});
```

Comment: If the parameter already exists inside the querystring, its value gets updated, great job!

Comment: newQueryVars will always be true though, so the last if statement won't work as intended.

Answer (score 9):

`window.location.href = window.location.href + "?search=" + escape( $("#someId").val());` ?

Comment: If the URL already has a querystring, won't this add to it rather than replace it?  You'll end up with multiple ?search segments.

Comment: @great_llama is correct. Instead of window.location.href you can use window.location.pathname. It will give you the url without querystring.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
window.location = "/currentpage.aspx?search=" + escape( $("#someId").val());
```

or

```
window.location = window.location.pathname + "?search=" + escape( $("#someId").val());
```

Etc...

Answer (score 3):

The problem with appending something to `window.location.href` is what if you have already done that? You'll just keep appending `"?search=..."` multiple times. More importantly, it's more complicated than it needs to be.

You're already using jQuery. Why not just do this?

```
<form id="search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search">
</form>
<a href="#" id="go">Search</a>
```

with:

```
$(function() {
  $("#go").click(function() {
    $("#search").submit();
    return false;
  });
});
```

and then you don't have to worry about the right URL, encoding, etc.

Comment: This won't add a querystring

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the wrong location property if you only want to change the search string. I think you want to do this:

```
location.search = "?search=" + encodeURIComponent( $("#someId").val());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').click(function(e){

         window.location = "?search=" + encodeURIComponent($("#someId").val());

         //this line of code is intended for older ie and might work,
         //because I don't remember it exactly
        e.stopPropagation();

         return false;
     });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

you need to prepend the actual base url

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "?search=" + escape( $("#someId").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

What part isn't working?

Try encodeURI() rather than escape().

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function() {

 document.location.href += "?search=" + encodeURIComponent($("#myTextBox").val());


});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function Redirect()
      {
    window.location.href = "URL_TO_BE_Redircted";
      }
```

then In button (asp.net)

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnRedirect" onClientClick="Redirect();return false;"/>
```

So after clicking on the button the control will go at serverside , and there
   you can access the Querystring you form !