# jQuery split/replace part of URL

Tags: jquery, url, replace, split

I have this url

`http://9001/transactions`

I have buttons that need to change the url e.g

```
http://9001/transactions?type=all
http://9001/transactions?type=confirmed
http://9001/transactions?type=unconfirmed
```

how would I go about replacing the string after transactions. I have the click functions in place just need to know what to put inside them.

the url will change so this cannot be dependant on anything before transactions (if that makes sense). Sorry if questions is vague but in a massive rush to get this done.

Comment: Do you want to be able to change only the parameters? Like type

Comment: I just need to change the string after "transactions" so for example when I click the "all" button it changes to "transactions?type=all" but when I click the confirmed button it changes to "transactions?type=confirmed"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10235376/733347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function that does exactly this, it reloads the current page, and has full support for changing existing url variables (as well as adding new ones). All you have to do is pass an object literal to the function. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10235376/733347

In your case all you'd need to do is call the function as so

```
reloadWithQueryStringVars({"type": "all"});
```

or

```
reloadWithQueryStringVars({"type": "confirmed"});
```

or

```
reloadWithQueryStringVars({"type": "unconfirmed"});
```

on the click events of your buttons

Here's the entire function for reference:

```
function reloadWithQueryStringVars (queryStringVars) {
    var existingQueryVars = location.search ? location.search.substring(1).split("&") : [],
        currentUrl = location.search ? location.href.replace(location.search,"") : location.href,
        newQueryVars = {},
        newUrl = currentUrl + "?";
    if(existingQueryVars.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < existingQueryVars.length; i++) {
            var pair = existingQueryVars[i].split("=");
            newQueryVars[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }
    }
    if(queryStringVars) {
        for (var queryStringVar in queryStringVars) {
            newQueryVars[queryStringVar] = queryStringVars[queryStringVar];
        }
    }
    if(newQueryVars) { 
        for (var newQueryVar in newQueryVars) {
            newUrl += newQueryVar + "=" + newQueryVars[newQueryVar] + "&";
        }
        newUrl = newUrl.substring(0, newUrl.length-1);
        window.location.href = newUrl;
    } else {
        window.location.href = location.href;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build a function to change the GET param...

```
var updateGetParam = function(key, value) {

    window.location.search = window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("([?&;])" + key + "=.*?(&|;|$)"), "$1" + key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "$2");

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JchAU/).

You should run the user input through a regex escaping function first.

Comment: makes no sense to me whatsoever, can you explain it a little better please?

Comment: @OliMillington It's a regular expression that replaces the existing GET param with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

See if this code works for you:

```
var href = window.location.href;

// This assumes the value of your button is the action and each
// button has the class button applied. Modify as necessary
$('.button').click(function (event) {
    if (href.lastIndexOf('?') !== -1) {
        href.replace(/\?(.*)/, '?type=' + $(this).val());
    } else {
        href += '?type=' + $(this).val();
    }
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

Comment: can you look at my updated question please, it kind of worked

Comment: still doesnt replace the current string

Comment: @OliMillington now it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

A very crude solution but it is easier to understand and implement, see if it helps

```
var url = "http://9001/transactions?type=unconfirmed"; //in live environment, replace with var url = window.location.href;
var urlArray = url.split('?');
var urlArrayLength = url.split('?').length;


urlArray[urlArrayLength - 1] = "type=newValue";


url  = urlArray.join('?');

alert(url)
```