# I want to find replace one url query parameter with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace a dynamic url query parameter with another parameter.

Eg. like my url is:

http://www.mysite.com/209-0539.prd?pageLevel=&skuId=111-4567&sc_cmp=pcp_GSF_Batteries+%26+Electrical+Accessories_209-0539

I want to replace everything starting after

```
&sc_cmp=pcp_GSF_Batteries+%26+Electrical+Accessories_209-0539
```

and add something like *& new Static string*

My final url should look like:

http://www.mysite.com/209-0539.prd?pageLevel=&skuId=111-4567& new static string.

Thanks

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10235376/733347

Comment: you should first show us what you've tried so far. it will also help you to learn more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to include another library, following lets you add as many search items you want removed and add as many as you like without a lot of code

```
/* array of search keys to remove*/
var removeSearch = ['sc_cmp']; 

/* array of new search items*/
var newSearchitem = ['image=cool']; 
var url = location.href; 

var pageUrl = url.split('?')[0];

var urlSearch = url.split('?')[1].split('&');
/* store search items in array */
var newSearchArr = [];
/* loop over exisiting search items and store keepers*/
for (i = 0; i < urlSearch.length; i++) {
    var key = urlSearch[i].split('=')[0];
    if ($.inArray(key, removeSearch) == -1) {
        newSearchArr.push(urlSearch[i])
    }
}

$.merge(newSearchArr, newSearchitem);

var newUrl = pageUrl + '?' + newSearchArr.join('&')
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9VPUX/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use the cool [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) library, then it's as easy as:

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com/209-0539.prd?pageLevel=&skuId=111-4567&sc_cmp=pcp_GSF_Batteries+%26+Electrical+Accessories_209-0539";

url = URI(url).removeSearch("sc_cmp").addSearch("newvar","newval");

// http://www.mysite.com/209-0539.prd?pageLevel=&skuId=111-4567&newvar=newval
alert(url);
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LE6a/) .